# How do you prove that $A\cap B=B$ is equivalent to $B\subseteq A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

My question is regarding how to prove that $A\cap B=B\iff B\subseteq A$. I can understand it logically: let $x$ be an arbitrary element in set $B$. Since $A\cap B=B$, this means that $x$ must be an element of both $A$ and $B$, because it's in their intersection. Therefore, $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. But I don't know how to go further.

Comment: If $B\subseteq A$, then for all $x\in B$ you have $x\in A$. This is because the definition of $B\subseteq A$ gives $x\in B\implies x\in A$. Since you have $x\in B$, then you can derive $x\in A$. Therefore, you have both $x\in B$ and $x\in A$. The definition of $A\cap B$ implies that $x\in A\cap B$. The definition of $\subseteq$ gives, from $\forall x\in B\implies x\in A\cap B$ that $B\subset A\cap B$. The inclusion $A\cap B\subset B$ you can get from the definition of $A\cap B$ and $\subseteq$.

Comment: @NDB Please do not answer questions in the comments.

Comment: Your argument is almost a correct proof of one of the two implications you need. It should end with $B \subseteq A$ . Then start from $B \subseteq A$ and prove the other assertion.

Answer (score 3):

Let us prove first that $A\cap B = B$ implies that $B\subseteq A$. If $x\in B = A\cap B$, this implies that $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. In particular, $x\in A$. Consequently, the proposed result holds. Suppose now that $B\subseteq A$. If $x\in B$, then $x\in A$, that is to say $x\in A\cap B$. On the other hand, if $x\in A\cap B$, then $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. In particular, $x\in B$ and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose first that $A\cap B=B$ and let $x\in B$. Then $x\in A\cap B$, i.e., in particular, $x\in A$.
Conversely, let $B\subset A$. Then $A\cap B=B$.\

In case you are wondering there is another iff condition that one can use: $A\cap B=B\iff B\subset A \iff A\triangle B=A\setminus B. $